# Using class member as key in a std::map of said class

Tags: c++, oop, architecture

I have a class with an enum class member variable which is intended to be used as a description of the instantiated object, there will never be two instantiated objects of the same type, example:

```
class A
{
   enum class Type { Type1, Type2, ...} type;
}
```

I want to store all instantiated objects within a collection for easy access based on the type, so I think that a map would be suitable:

```
class B
{
   std::map<A::Type, A> components;
}
```

However, something tells me this is not great design because I am effectively duplicating the same data, i.e. using a class (A) member variable (*type*) as a key that points to a value (object of class A) that also holds the same information. The other alternative would be not to use the enum as a *class A* member variable but define that enum within *class B* and only using it as a key.
Any advice?

Comment: `std::set<A, CustomComparerOnType>`? (if instances are immutable).

Comment: nothing wrong with it. it's more about what use case you have.

Comment: advice: Dont ponder too much about what would be great design. Design serves some purpose and if storing the key twice is what you need, then what can be wrong about it? You can consider a `std::vector<A>` as alternative but then you miss all the convenience of a `map`

Comment: @appleapple It's effectively to store a collection of components (class A) that represent a cost (amount, quantity, etc.) so class B would be used to effectively perform actions like summating cost of all components, but I still need a way to access individual components for cost and so a map would be ideal instead of storing the objects in a std::vector and iterating through it using an if statement to get the actual component type.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number thanks for the advice - I can definitely overthink something - , as I mentioned in my comment to apple apple, I would like the map because I want easy access to individual objects in a collection, but otherwise I would be employing a vector.

Comment: Boost provides [intrusive](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/intrusive.html) set that you can use [as map](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/intrusive/map_multimap.html)

Comment: @SimStil Forgot about the `map`, Is it nature to have `type` inside A? this decision should not take care of how it's used by B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets consider the key features of the map

- unique keys
- ordererd with respect to keys
- keys are `const`, values not
- key are stored seperately from the mapped values

Your requirement is in contrast with the last bullet so now you can consider what compromise you can make with the others.

- `std::set<A,CustomComparator>`

With a custom comparator you can ensure unique keys that can be stored in the values and sorting can be the same as with the map. But elements are `const`. You could use `mutable` but this bypasses const-correctness and should be used with care.

- `std::vector<A>`

This is the most flexible but you need to take care of almost everything you got from the map manually. It can be feasible if you populate the vector only once and then only access elements, because then you need to check for uniqueness and sort the elements only once.

- some non-std container

Jarod42 suggested boosts intrusive [set](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/intrusive.html). There might be other non-standard containers that fit your needs.

- just stay with `std::map<A::type,A>`

If the key is only a single enum value, then storing the keys twice is an easy solution that has some cost, but allows you to use a `map` when that is the container you want to use.

- Not store the keys in the mapped_values in the first place

This is actually the cleanest solution when the mapped_values are only stored in the map and not used outside of the map. And when you still need the mapped_values together with the keys outside of the map you can use `std::pair<type::A,A>`.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive response. I am inclined to use the last suggested solution based on your comparison of the other options.